# matplotlib candlestick chart bar output error - seems to be plotting more than one timeframe on single bar

Tags: matplotlib, candlestick-chart

I am attempting to plot a candlestick chart using matplotlib, with hourly candles. However my output looks strange and it seems to be plotting multiple "hours" on one candle.

My code is as follows:

```
cursor = conx.cursor()
query= 'SELECT ticker,date,time,open,low,high,close FROM eurusd WHERE date > "2014-01-28"'
cursor.execute(query)
for line in cursor:
    #appendLine in correct format for candlesticks - date,open,close,high,low
    date=date2num(line[1])
    open=(line[3])
    high=(line[5])
    low=(line[4])
    close=(line[6])

    appendLine = date,open,close,high,low
    candleAr.append(appendLine)

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = plt.subplot(1,1,1)

candlestick(ax1, candleAr, width=0.6, colorup='g', colordown='r')

ax1.grid(True)


plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.show()
```

And my output looks like the following:

[image]

Do I have to manipulate the "date2num" function to account for the fact that my data is hourly and not daily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to answer my own question - It was due to the date2num output having repeated values and was cramming all the days hourly bars into one. I had to add my date and time together to get a datetime, and then use the date2num on the date time (rather than date)

```
date=[]
open=[]
low=[]
high=[]
close=[]
candleAr=[]

for line in cursor:
    time1=datetime.time(0,0)
    time=datetime.datetime.combine(line[1],time1)
    time=time+line[2]
    appendLine = date2num(time),line[3],line[6],line[5],line[4]
```